# What is the name for the favor which goes against your best interest?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Many languages have this expression but I am not sure how it is expressed in English.

Its example would be:

> I helped him cheat his way through college, now he has no job. I did
>   him ____ favor.

Hope it makes sense, and thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: How do you say it in one of these other languages?

Comment: In my language it is called "bear favor" and since I am for Balkans other languages in region have that expression.  Example of similar phrase would be "Sisyphus task" - task leading nowhere, dead-end.

Comment: Normally one would simply say "I did him no favor."

Comment: Same in German (Baerendienst) and in Scandinavian languages (though in Denmark, the young have started to think it means a really big favour).

Comment: **The bear's service** is used in many languages - it is based on the fable "The Bear and the Gardener"(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bear_and_the_Gardener) and its Krylov's version "The Hermit and The Bear" (https://fablesofaesop.com/hermit-bear.html). I am surprised that the phrase apparently is not known in English, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is **disservice**.

> **disservice:** an act intended to help that turns out badly

([Princeton WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=disservice))

> I helped him cheat his way through college, now he can't get a job. I did
>   him a disservice.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **counterproductive** and **detrimental**.

> counterproductive: thwarting the achievement of an intended goal; tending to defeat one's purpose [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/counterproductive?s=t)
>
> *I helped him cheat his way through college, which eventuated in being counterproductive, since now he has no job.*
>
> detrimental: causing loss or injury; harmful; damaging [Random
> House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/detrimental)

Alternately, **double-edged**, or the phrase **work against someone**, might fit the bill.

> *I helped him cheat his way through college; now he has no job. I did him a double-edged favor.*
>
> *I helped him cheat his way through college, which eventually worked
> against him, since now he has no job.*

Answer (score 0):

A backhanded favour, maybe? Just like when you pay someone a "backhanded compliment".